# Trying to upload a filename that has been hashed to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to AWS S3 with the file key being the date of the file creation concatenated to the MD5 hashing of the file itself. I have no problem generating the hash but when trying to upload the file I get the following error.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidURI) when calling the PutObject operation: Couldn't parse the specified URI.
```

The file I'm trying to upload is a downloaded webpage.

Here's my code

```
#new_page_content holds the downloaded html file I'm trying to upload.
new_page_content_encode("UTF-8") 
current_time = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_", time.gmtime())
md5_hash_func = hashlib.md5()
md5_hash_func.update(new_page_content.encode("UTF-8"))
hashed_string = md5_hash_func.digest()
key_string = current_time + hashed_string

os.remove(LOCAL_PATH)
new_local_file = io.open(LOCAL_PATH, mode="w", encoding="utf-8")
new_local_file.write(new_page_content)
new_local_file.close()

#Uploading starts here
s3 = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    )
data = open(LOCAL_PATH, "rb")
s3.upload_fileobj(data, BUCKET, key_string)
data.close()
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that I'm using unsafe letter as defined by the documentation. I was wondering if there's any ability to bypass that while uploading files?

I've seen a similar question regarding downloading files but I couldn't quite figure out how to convert the solution to uploads.

Comment: "Couldn't parse the specified URI" - what's the URI?

Comment: The URI is generated based on the key_string by the function `upload_fileobj`. I do not know how to generate the URI itself from the boto3 library.
I've edited my answer with some more information.

Comment: It is probably upset with some of the characters in the generated key. Can you provided an example of the Key that caused this error? Have you tried uploading via `aws s3 cp` just to test whether the Key is acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I used `hexdigest` instead of `digest` and got safe characters.